# Trying to print out a input text the number of times the user wrote in the secound input using a while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have two input fields and a button. When the user clicks the button, I want it to display the text the user wrote in the first input the amount of times the user wrote in the second input.

I understand you have to use a while loop for this. What am I doing wrong here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>While Loop</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = btn;

    function btn() {
      document.getElementById("btn").onclick = showText;
    }

    function showText() {
      var text = "";
      var inputOne = document.getElementById("txtBox").value;
      var inputTwo = document.getElementById("numBox").value;
      while (inputOne < inputTwo) {
        text += inputOne;
        inputOne++;
      }
      document.getElementById("showCode").innerHTML = text;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="txtBox"><br/>
  <input type="number" id="numBox"><br/>
  <button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
  <p id="showCode"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `inputOne` is a text, you cannot increment it (you can't do `inputOne++`), instead, use another variable, let's call it `i`, to control the while loop:

```js
window.onload = btn;

function btn() {
  document.getElementById("btn").onclick = showText;
}

function showText() {
  var text = "";
  var inputOne = document.getElementById("txtBox").value;
  var inputTwo = document.getElementById("numBox").value;
  var i=1; // to control the loop
  while (i <= inputTwo) {    // i goes from 1 to inputTwo
    text += inputOne;
    i++;
  }
  document.getElementById("showCode").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtBox"><br/>
<input type="number" id="numBox"><br/>
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
<p id="showCode"></p>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>While Loop</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = btn;

    var count = 0;

    function btn() {
      document.getElementById("btn").onclick = showText;
    }

    function showText() {

      var text = "";
      console.log("Text: "+text);

      var inputOne = document.getElementById("txtBox").value;
      console.log("Input One: "+inputOne);

      var inputTwo = document.getElementById("numBox").value;
      console.log("Input 2: "+inputTwo);

      count=count+1;
      console.log("Times: "+count);

      document.getElementById("numBox").value = count;

      document.getElementById("showCode").innerHTML = text;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="txtBox"><br/>
  <input type="number" id="numBox"><br/>
  <button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
  <p id="showCode"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the while loop you can use a for loop like this:

```
for( let i = inputTwo; i>0; i--) {
    text += inputOne;
}
```